# DB Strategy on MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am asked to prepare a Database Strategy for my Company? My company is using MSSQL Server 2016 with 1 instance and 10 databases. What should I include in the Database Strategy? Any format or template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In strategy what do you try to ask?

- RTO: Recovery time objective, how long do you have to restore data,
- RPO: Recovery point objective, how much data are you allowed to lose when reverting to a restore,
- SLA: How fast does it need to be and how are maintenance windows
  managed between the data owners,
- Features: What version of SQL server do you need,
- Data sizing: How much data will the system have in N years from now, do you have a storage strategy, RAM needs?,
- Data retention: how long do you need to retain the data for legal compliance,
- Users: Data sensitivity and authentication schemes that need to be supported,
- Lineage: where does the data come from and where does it go.
- Governance: who in the business (not IT) owns what data and has authority to grant and restrict access
- PII: what is held and what uses have been agreed to